# Prop from parent component returns empty on one of the childs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, components

I have a map component with two childs - `GSearchVehicle` & `MapView` - with a `positions` prop. On the `zoomInVehicle` function the `positions` always returns with a empty array, but on the `renderCustomCluster` function it returns full.

The `zoomInVehicle` is a function triggered by a custom onPress on `GSearchVehicle`, it returns the vehicle id that I want to use on the `zoomInVehicle`. The problem is the `positions` prop not returning filled.

This is bugging me 'cause `positions` is filled on all places of the `GMap` component, but only on that function it returns empty... and it's not a problem about waiting the positions request because it's already filled by the time you call that `zoomInVehicle` function.

What is the meaning of this behavior? Something with the scope of `GSearchVehicle` and `MapView`? I can't see why `positions` is empty only on that function.

```js
const GMap: React.FC<GMapProps> = ({ positions, selectMarker, selectedMarker }) => {
  const mapRef = useRef<MapViewProps | any>(null);

  console.log(positions); // [{...}] <--- NOT EMPTY!

  const zoomInVehicle = (vehicleId: number): void => {
    console.log(vehicleId); // 15486
    console.log(positions); // [] <--- EMPTY!
    // ...
  };

  const renderCustomCluster = (cluster: any) => {
    console.log(positions) // [{...}] <--- NOT EMPTY!
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <>
      <GSearchVehicle
        placeholder="Digite a placa ou descrição"
        onPress={zoomInVehicle}
      />

      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION}
        provider={null}
        showsCompass={false}
        renderCluster={renderCustomCluster}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        onRegionChangeComplete={getRegionZoom}
      >
        <UrlTile urlTemplate={TILE_URL} shouldReplaceMapContent />

        {/* Draw vehicle marker */}
        { positions.map((position) => (
          <Marker
            key={position.adhesion.id}
            tracksViewChanges={false}
            coordinate={position.coordinates}
            onPress={() => selectMarker(position)}
          >
            <GVehicleMarker
              key={position.adhesion.id}
              position={position}
            />
          </Marker>
        ))}

        {/* ... */}
      </MapView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, on the `GSearchVehicle` component my memoized functions were missing the `positions` prop on it's dependencies.

```js
  const memoizedItems = useMemo(() => renderItem, [vehiclesGroup, positions]);
  const memoizedHeader = useMemo(() => renderSectionHeader, [vehiclesGroup, positions]);
```